# How to upload a file from app in VC++ 6 to a web server?

Tags: http, visual-c++, file-upload

I have an application in VC++ 6 (not MFC) , feature requires it to upload a file to a web server on regular basis. Web server is under our control, anonymous upload scripts/page are already setup that would accept a file manually.

How to program in VC++ 6 to upload? which classes to use?
I understand it is much possible with smtp and ftp but how through http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 2000 upwards, you could use [InternetWriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385128(VS.85).aspx) API

Open session using [InternetOpen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385096(VS.85).aspx)

Open URL using [InternetOpenUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385098(VS.85).aspx)

and create buffers to read file from the filesystem and use InternetWriteFile to send it to the server opened by InternetOpenUrl

To use HTTP specifically, you could use [WinHttpWriteData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385098(VS.85).aspx) API

support functions needed for this is similar to the above, and it's well defined on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382925(VS.85).aspx)